# since_ID in mentions_timeline returns most recent tweet - not sure if issue is with Python or Twitter API

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am very new to Python, very new to the Twitter API, and not sure which I've messed up here (which is making it hard to research a solution).

I've made a simple twitter bot which queries the mentions_timeline, and responds to at-replies with one of a predetermined list of responses (sorry in advance for the emojis). The problem is that every time it runs it responds to all the most recent at-replies, whether or not they've already been replied to.

I've tried to get round this by writing the most recent mention ID the bot has replied to to a file, and passing that value to the since_ID of the mentions_timeline the next time the script is run. As far as I understand, the bot should then only see tweets it hasn't responded to, but instead it sees the most recent at-replies, including those it's already replied to.

I get the same results whether or not I increment the mention ID by 1 before running the query - I thought maybe since_ID was inclusive, but it appears to make no difference. Essentially since_ID seems to have zero effect on what the query returns.

I'm not sure what to do - I don't know if the problem is in how I've passed the value to the Twitter API, or if there's an error in my code. Any help would be appreciated!

This is the script in question:

```
### find the last mention ID ###
fp=open("lastid.py","r")
last_id_replied = fp.read()

### increment by 1 (or not?!) ###
# last_id_replied = (int(last_id_replied) + 1)
# print(last_id_replied)   

### iterate through mentions ###
mentions = api.mentions_timeline(count=1, since_ID=last_id_replied)
print (mentions)
for mention in mentions:
  fp=open("lastid.py","w")
  fp.write(str(mention.id))

  ### choose a heart ###
  atheart = randrange(0,3)
  if atheart == 0:
    atheartprint = ''
  if atheart == 1:
    atheartprint = ''
  if atheart == 2:
    atheartprint = ''
  if atheart == 3:
    atheartprint = ''

  ### post the tweet ###
  sn = mention.user.screen_name
  m = ("@%s " + atheartprint) % (sn)
  s = api.update_status(m, mention.id)
  print(last_id_replied)
  fp=open("lastid.py","w")
  fp.write(str(mention.id))
  print("done messaging people!")
```

Comment: Don't forget to close your files, or you could use `with open()` method which is way more better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, I think, by completely changing the method used to get tweets - I've used the cursor to iterate through them instead and it appears to be working. I don't really understand why it doesn't work without cursor though.

```
query = '@name'
max_tweets = 20
recent_mentions = [status for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.mentions_timeline, q=query, since_id=last_id_replied).items(max_tweets)]
print recent_mentions
```